# Confused about 'this' keyword in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out why the below 3 ways of using  `this` keyword don't work

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="i1" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="i2" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="i3" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
// Output a list of href ids and append them to the ul element
$('ul li a').each(function() {
    $('<li>' + this.id + '</li>').appendTo('ul') // this works
    // $(this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
    // (this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
    // $(this).attr('id').appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
});
```

Here is also [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZPnP/2/)

Could somebody explain why none of the 3 code snippets which are commented out work?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? duplicate listitems in `ul`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

This does not work because jQuery is expecting you to supply an element, array of elements or string selector inside the `$()` construct. By supplying a string selector like `i1` which won't match anything, the `appendTo` will not know which object it should be working on.

```
(this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

This does not work because the value returned by `id` does not have an `appendTo` method - note you're not using the `$` here to invoke jQuery.

```
$(this).attr('id').appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

This does not work because `appendTo` will append the `li` object, not the string returned by `attr('id')`

The problem itself seems to stem from the fact that you seem a little confused about `appendTo()` - basically it appends elements, not string values. Have a read of [the API](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) for more information.

Comment: `$(this.id)` is a valid tagname selector. And the third one is trying to call `.appendTo` on a string, because `$(this).attr("id")` returns a string

Comment: @Esailija true, but not in the OPs case, I'll clarify.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right, I think I wrongly assumed that if `.appendTo` accepts an HTML string, it would also accept a string. Still wondering why it wouldn't accept a string and append it. Is there a method in jQuery which would append whatever you pass it?

Comment: If you reverse your selector to start with the target element you can append text simply with `append()`, try this: `$('ul').append(this.id);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also, would you mind explaining why `$(this).attr('id').appendTo('ul')` would append the `li` object?

Comment: @finspin it wouldn't, the explanation is wrong. `$(this).attr("id")` returns a string like `"i1"`, and then attempts to call `.appendTo` on the string (so it's same as `"any string here".appendTo("ul")` which causes an error because strings don't have `appendTo` method.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this.id).appendTo('ul')` is same as `$("i1").appendTo('ul')`. Find all elements with tag name "i1", none are found so this does nothing.

`(this.id).appendTo("ul")` is same as `"i1".appendTo("ul")`, no such method exists in strings

The third commented out snippet is exactly the same as the second - calling method `.appendTo` on a string.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the DOM element which underlies jQuery object you work with inside each `each` iteration.

In your example the following code:

```
$("ul li a").each(function() {
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

will work in the same way as:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("i1").href);
console.log(document.getElementById("i2").href);
console.log(document.getElementById("i3").href);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// $(this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
$('#'+this.id).appendTo('ul') // this will work
```

To use the ID selector, you need to add `#` prefix.

---

```
// (this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

`(this.id)`    it is not jQuery object, so `.appendTo` is undefined.

---

```
// $(this).attr('id').appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

`$(this).attr('id')` is not jQuery object, so `.appendTo` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

- `$(this.id)` tries to use the ID (string) value as a jQuery selector. That's not what you want.
- `(this.id)` is the same as `this.id` - the parens just group here. They are not a function call. In both cases, there is no `.appendTo` function on string objects, which is what `this.id` is.
- Pretty much the same problem as in the previous bullet point for `$(this).attr('id')`. That expression evaluates to a string, which has no `.appendTo` function.

In all cases, you should get in the habit of using a debugger, and looking in your JavaScript error console, because #2 and #3 will print very obvious errors describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// $(this).attr('id').appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

Doesn't work because `.attr()` return a value, not the actual item. Use `.find()` instead !

```
// (this.id).appendTo('ul') // this doesn't work
```

Doesn't work because `this.id` is not a valid jquery item.

So if you want to use an id, you need to use

```
$('#'+this.id).appendTo('ul')
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I feel like your code would be a lot cleaner if you avoided the use of "this" in this instance altogether:

http://jsfiddle.net/DZPnP/3/

```
$ul = $('#someULid');

$('ul li a').each(function( index, linkElement) {
    $linkElement = $(linkElement);
    $('<li>' + $linkElement.attr('id') + '</li>').appendTo( $ul );
});
```